# Find limit of sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

For the sequence {s$_n$} defined as:

{$s_n$} = $1$ + $(-1)^n$ + $1/2^n$

Let $E$ be the set of all subsequential limits of the ${s_n}$.
Then $sup E = 3$ and $inf E = 0$

Is the above conclusion right ?
If not please explain why it is wrong.

*what I did*
I found the $sup$ $s_n$ = 3 (the maximum value it can get), and took limit tending n->infinity (which I got independent here), thus concluded similar for $inf E$.

Please explain in general how to find supE and infE in any sequence.I don't think it is right as I have nowhere used that $E$ is the set of subsequential limits.

Comment: $1/2^n$ tends zero as $n\rightarrow \infty,$ therefore $\lim \sup s_n=2$ and $\lim \inf s_n=0.$

Comment: @Suhail but limit is taken on $sup E$ which is 3.

Comment: What is difference between $\lim \sup s_n$ & $\sup E$?

Comment: @Suhail In the first one limit is taken on the sup and in second just the sup.

Comment: The set $E$ of subsequential limits is just the two-element set $\{0,2\}$. Its sup and max is $2$, its inf and min is $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sir how did you get that please explain.

Comment: I looked at the sequence, visualized the geometry. One can give a formal proof,  but calculating the first few terms should be persuasive enough.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks I got that, but how do you conclude that $E$ has only two elements.I mean there are many subsequences possible all that are converging to only 2 and 0.How you arrive at this

Comment: The terms $1/2^n$ are after a while negligible. If $n$ is big then $s_n$ is either very close to $2$ or very close to $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.